# Swapping icons of 2 jbutton

Tags: java

I want to change the icon of 2 Jbuttons by selecting one and then the next to swap their icons. Something like candy crush or bejeweled.
I want to use action listener to accomplish this, how should i go about doing it?

this is the gui of my program:

```
public class UI implements Runnable {

private JFrame _frame;
private Model _model;
private ArrayList<JButton> _tiles;

public void run() {
    _model = new Model();
    _frame = new JFrame();
    _frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,5));

    _tiles = new ArrayList<JButton>();
    for (int i=0; i<25; i++) {
        JButton tile = new JButton();
        tile.setBackground(Color.white);
    //this just pick out random icon file from a folder
        tile.setIcon(_model.randomIcon()); 
        tile.addActionListener(new ButtonBorderHandler(_model,tile));
    //this is the actionlistener that i want to implement the swap on
        tile.addActionListener(new ButtonSwapHandler();
        _tiles.add(tile);
    }
```

i've tried doing it like so

```
public class ButtonSwapHandler implements ActionListener{

JButton _button1;
JButton _button2;
Model _model;
UI _ui;

public ButtonSwapHandler(UI u,Model m, JButton b1, JButton b2){
    _model=m;
    _button1=b1;
    _button2=b2;
    _ui =u;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

//this line should give me the position of the first button i press
    int i = _ui.getTiles().indexOf(e.getSource());

//this is the part where i dont know how to keep going
//i want to know where is the 2nd button that i clicked
    int j = _ui.getTiles().indexOf(e.

// this is the method i wrote to make the swap
// it just the Collections.swap(tile,positionOfButton1,postionOfButton2)
    _model.swap(ui._tile,i,j);
}
```

Comment: Have your tried repaint() or revalidate() after the swap?

Comment: the problem is that i dont know how to swap because i dont know which button is pressed second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic needs little clarity. You are creating a 5x5 grid, where you are populating the buttons.

For example like this:

```
0  1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8  9
10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24
```

But, when you are clicking on a button, how do you ensure the direction of swap? Say, if the user clicks on button 7, which adjacent button of 7 should be selected for swapping?

So, the missing piece of your logic is the direction.

For example:

If the swap always happens with immediate left button, you can calculate the swap button like `indexOf(selectedButton)-1`. Again, the swap may be happening on conditional basis only if that row in that two dimensional grid has immediate left button.

**Update:**

If the action is supposed to happen only after clicking two buttons, then you need to create one more class which actually keeps track of number of buttons clicked then swaps when count==2.

Following is a modified example:

```
public class ButtonClicksCounter {
    static ArrayList<JButton> _buttonsClicked = new ArrayList<JButton>();
    public static void addButton(JButton btn) {
        _buttonsClicked.add(btn);
    }

    public static int getButtonClicksCount() {
        return _buttonsClicked.size();
    }

    public static void clearButtonClicksCount() {
        _buttonsClicked.clear();
    }

    public ArrayList<JButton> getButtonsClicked() {
        return _buttonsClicked;
    }

}

public class ButtonSwapHandler implements ActionListener{


JButton _button;
Model _model;
UI _ui;

public ButtonSwapHandler(UI u, Model m, JButton b1){
    _model=m;
    _button=b1;
    _ui =u;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   //Add the button
   ButtonClicksCounter.addButton((JButton)e.getSource());

   //Check if count==2
   if(ButtonClicksCounter.getButtonClicksCount()==2) {
      ArrayList<JButton> buttonsToSwap = ButtonClicksCounter.getButtonsClicked();

      //Get positions
      int i = _ui.getTiles().indexOf(buttonsToSwap[0]);
      int j = _ui.getTiles().indexOf(buttonsToSwap[1]);

      //Swap
      _model.swap(ui._tile,i,j);

      //Clear selection
      ButtonClicksCounter.clearButtonClicksCount();
   }

}
```

Comment: i was hoping to swap horizontally and vertically. with your example of button 7, i know i can perform action on it with     indexOf(e.getSource). but, i dont know how to find out which buttons is pressed second